# Angular Firebase: Property 'database' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use the firebase.database.reference in my Angular project but I cannot get rid of the follow errors even after searching the web.

I am getting the error "Property 'database' does not exist" for the following line

```
let dbRef = firebase.database().ref('students/');
```

Also, I got the error for "Cannot find name 'firebase' so I added

```
import * as firebase from '@firebase/app';
```

this removed the 'firebase' name error but I wonder if this is the best way to import firebase?

I am using Angular 5

```
  import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
 "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
 "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above method is deprecated in the latest release. you need to use

```
import { AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from "angularfire2/firestore";
```

and

```
 constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
```

thsen use it as,

```
 this.db.collection('whatever');
```

Comment: isn't FirebaseListObservable deprecated?  I thought FirebaseListObservable became AngularFireList

Comment: check the follwoing code https://github.com/yahyameo/Angular-5-using-firebase/blob/cf861bf435b45180c5cc2954bc2fcea7872878cb/src/app/services/apps.service.ts